# Possible plain text needed on a congruence modulo - based encryption

Tags: encryption, number-theory, decryption, congruence

Suppose `m` is a positive integer converted from the plain text in bytes.

And there are two positive integers `a`, `b` which satisfies $a^2=1+4919b^2$ in the encryption process. (`a` and `b` are both unknown)

The cipher text is `x` which satisfies $x = (am+b) mod  p$ where p is **known** and is a large prime number.

For some reasons, the cipher texts are shuffled by group. And so I got several possible values of x (which are all very large)

Given the cues above, how to get the possible integer number `m`? The possible `m` can be checked by deciding if the plain text converted from the `m` makes sense.

Any detailed solution would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Could you be more verbose as to what you mean by ciphertexts were shuffled by a group?